# getServerSideProps not working in nextjs error in mapping

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to do  getServerSideProps  but I am getting the following error what is the error I am doing

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

export default function Answershooks(props, { posts }) {


  return (
    <div className="answerhook">
       {posts.map((personData, index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={index} className="cardmobile">
            <Card.Body>
              <p className="answersize">{personData.Answers} </p>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
         );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  
  const res = await fetch("https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/" + props.id);
  console.log(res);
  console.log("dada");
  const posts = await res.json();

  // By returning { props: { posts } }, the Blog component
  // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}
```

i have added added a file stucture screenshot so u undersand how my files are placed

[image]

Comment: Can you console.log(res) and post the response please

Comment: @Matt nothing is loging when i do console.log i have updated question how i console.loged

Comment: Then your fetch is failing. You should really make a wrapper component for the fetch to catch the error.

Comment: @Matt pls help me how to achive this

Comment: Use Answershooks({ posts })  instead of Answershooks(props, { posts })

Comment: What is props.id in your fetch method ? It comes from nowhere. You can't access props in getServerSideProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you're trying to call `getServerSideProps` in `Answerhooks` but it's not a page component, so you cannot get data on the server as expected

Instead of having `getServerSideProps` in that, you can move your API call to `getServerSideProps` in `[itmid].jsx` (which is an actual page component) like below

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  var id = ctx.query.itmid;

  const queryRequest = fetch("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questone/" + id).then(async (res) => await res.json());
  const answerRequest = fetch("https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/" + id).then(async (res) => await res.json());
  const [posts, answerPosts] = await Promise.all([queryRequest, answerRequest]);

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      answerPosts
    }
  };
}
```

After that, you can get `answerPosts` from props for `Query`

```
function Query({ posts, answerPosts }) {
   return <Answerhooks answerPosts={answerPosts} />
}
```

Finally, you can have the data on props inside `Answerhooks` component

```
function Answershooks({ answerPosts }) {
   
   //TODO: Apply your logic with `answerPosts`
   console.log(answerPosts)

   return <div></div>
}
```

Comment: no props i am not getting value of posts

Comment: You can check [this document](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#using-getserversideprops-to-fetch-data-at-request-time) for the above implementation, @jisaks

Comment: you can destruct `{ posts }` from `props` instead of having the 2nd param for it, @jisaks

Comment: props i am passing from parent componet to child componet but { posts } i am passing from the getserversideprops

Comment: when consoleloging  posts  i get undefine and props i get the id that i pass from parent compoent

Comment: Hmm but if that is the case, could you share the parent component of `Answershooks`, too? @jisaks

Comment: One more thing you also need to keep in mind, if it's not a page component which is defined under `pages` folder, you cannot use `getServerSideProps` @jisaks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-fire-0t8db8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your URL will be `query/answerhooks`? If you don't access it that way, it means `answerhooks` is not a page component. Therefore, you cannot get data from `getServerSideProps` @jisaks

Comment: my url currently is like this http://localhost:3000/query/62114297f2f60a0023a83be0

Comment: https://www.wixten.com/query/616bf26acb0ac0002363e4e5   in live version it will be like this

Comment: if i pass https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/62114297f2f60a0023a83be0  my api will work

Comment: Do you call `Answerhooks` somewhere else? Could you share `[itmid].jsx` too? That is a potential component for the above URL. @jisaks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-fire-0t8db8?file=/src/App.js has the code of [itmid].jsx

Comment: the answerhook is a componetent inside [itmid].jsx

Comment: Error: Error serializing `.posts` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/query/[itmid]".
Reason: `object` ("[object Response]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the fetch error and work out why that is failing so make a new component.

fetchHandler.js

```
export async function fetchHandler(url){
  try{
      const res = await fetch(url);
      return res
  } catch(err){
      console.log(err); //this will tell us why it failed.
      return false //this gives us a condition we can use on the front end
    } 
}
```

Then your Answerhooks.

```
import {fetchHandler} from '../yourpath'

export default function Answershooks({ posts }) {


  return (
    <div className="answerhook">
       {posts.map((personData, index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={index} className="cardmobile">
            <Card.Body>
              <p className="answersize">{personData.Answers} </p>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
         );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

  const url = `https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/${ctx.query.id}`
  const res = await fetchHandler(url)
  console.log(res);
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts: posts === false ? [] : posts //Just to stop your app crashing
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: so i should make a new file called  fetchHandler.js

Comment: @jisaks yes make a new file then import

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    (store) =>
        async ({req}) => {

         const result =  await store.dispatch(fetchHome());

            return {
                props: {
                    list : result
                },
            };
        }
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).